# Union correct usage

Tags: c++, c++11

My understanding of a union is all its values are allocated in the same memory address and the memory space is as large as the largest member of the union. But I don't understand how we would actually use them.
This is a code where using a union is preferable according to [The C++ Programming Language](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_C++_Programming_Language.html?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ).

```
enum Type { str, num };

struct Entry {
     char* name;
     Type t;
     char* s;  // use s if t==str
     int i;    // use i if t==num
};

void f(Entry* p)
{
     if (p->t == str)
           cout << p->s;
     // ...
}
```

After this Bjarne says:

> The members s and i can never be used at the same time, so space is wasted. It can be easily recovered by specifying that both should be members of a union, like this:
>
>     union Value {
>          char* s;
>          int i;
>     };
>
>
> The language doesn’t keep track of which kind of value is held by a union, so the programmer must do that: 
>
>
>     struct Entry {
>          char* name;
>          Type t;
>          Value v; // use v.s if t==str; use v.i if t==num
>     };
>
>     void f(Entry* p)
>     {
>          if (p->t == str)
>                cout v.s;
>          // ...
>     }

Can anyone explain the resulting union code further? what will actually happen if we transform this into a union?

Comment: Unions are often used in networking when defining packets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have a 32-bit machine, with 32-bit integers and pointers.  Your struct might then look like this:

```
[0-3] name
[4-7] type
[8-11] string
[12-15] integer
```

That's 16 bytes, but since `type` (`t` in your code) determines which field is valid, we never need to actually store the `string` and `integer` fields at the same time.  So we can change the code:

```
struct Entry {
  char* name;
  Type t;
  union {
    char* s;  // use s if t==str
    int i;    // use i if t==num
  } u;
};
```

Now the layout is:

```
[0-3] name
[4-7] type
[8-11] string
[8-11] integer
```

In C++, whatever you assigned to most recently is the "valid" member of the union, but there is no way to know which one that is intrinsically, so you must store it yourself.  This technique is often called a "discriminated union", the "discriminator" being the `type` field.

So the second struct takes 12 bytes instead of 16.  If you're storing lots of them, or if they come from a network or disk, you might care about this.  Otherwise, it's not really important.

Comment: Oops I absolutely have no idea about this bit/byte thing. if I don't care about this, I don't have to use unions right?

Comment: Correct.  Most C++ projects do not use unions at all.  There are tons of features in C++ that you usually don't need.  Other examples: facets, `std::ios_base::xalloc()`, placement `new`, and lots more!

Answer (score 3):

For below union,

```
union mix_types {
  int l;
  struct {
    short hi;
    short lo;
    } s;
  char c[4];
} mix;
```

memory structure would be like :-

[image]

Comment: "memory structure would be like :-" - do you mind putting them into text? I can't read images. Thanks.

Comment: Explanation is already provided by@John, so I just used image. You can connect this with his explanation

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use unions is to access the same data using different types. An example is the DirectX matrix structure,

```
typedef struct _D3DMATRIX {
    union {
        struct {
            float        _11, _12, _13, _14;
            float        _21, _22, _23, _24;
            float        _31, _32, _33, _34;
            float        _41, _42, _43, _44;

        };
        float m[4][4];
    };
} D3DMATRIX;
```

Now you can do,

```
D3DMATRIX d;
d._11 = 20;
// Now the value of m[0][0] is 20
assert(d._11 == m[0][0]);
```

Comment: Note that 'nameless' unions and structs are actually a non-standard Microsoft Visual C++ extension (see [C4201](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c89bw853.aspx)). Technically you'd have to use ``struct D3DMATRIX { union D3DMATRIX1 { struct D3DMATRIX2 { ... }; float m[4][4]; };`` to be standard C++.

Comment: Also note that the pattern used by the legacy D3DXMath header is written for C compatibility. C++ does not require the ``typedef struct _X { ... } X;`` construction. You can just do ``struct D3DMATRIX { ... };``